# command not found: wrangler after installation of wrangler

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to install the Cloudflare wrangler in ubuntu and I am able to install using normal command but when I use wrangler --version I am getting an error `wrangler: command not found` and I have installed wrangler on the root using this command:

```
sudo npm install @cloudflare/wrangler -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

I have also used normal command:

```
npm i @cloudflare/wrangler
```

Here are the commands I've tried:

```bash
wrangler --help  # getting the above-mentioned error

wrangler generate my-worker # getting the above-mentioned error
```

But when I am using

```
npx wrangler generate my-worker
```

I am able to create the project.

When I am running

```
wrangler preview
```

it's the same error so don't know how to solve this issue.

I am using Node version v10.10.0 and npm version is v6.13.6

Comment: Which environment are you working on?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy i didn't get your question

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy can you please help me

Answer (score 2):

Your installation of wrangler was local to the project you're in, in order for the wrangler command to work, it needs to be installed globally. npx runs the local project installation of wrangler, that is why that command works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This appears to go against Cloudflare's recommendations: "Cloudflare recommends installing Wrangler locally into each of your projects. This allows you and your team to use the same Wrangler version, control Wrangler versions for each project, and rollback to an earlier version of Wrangler, if needed." ([source](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/wrangler/install-and-update/))

Comment: Use `node_modules/.bin/wrangler` or add `node_modules/.bin` to your path

Answer (score 1):

You can try `npx wrangler preview`